# Delete user profile from command line Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vbscript

Frequently I need to delete all of the user profiles on a computer except for two accounts. I would like to have a script that can perform this for me.

The script must work for Windows 7.

Company policy makes it difficult to download and use any third party utility, so downloading a tool that can accomplish the task is not an acceptable alternative.

Currently I have a vbscript that performs other related functions so if I could do it in VBscript that would be great. If there is a way to do it straight from the Windows command line, that works too I can just call that from my VB script.

I've looked online and I cannot find a way to do this with either VBscript or with a microsoft cmdline utility that comes installed by default on Windows 7.

Does anyone know how I could perform this?

Comment: Dunno man, I googled "VBScript delete profile" and got plenty of info. For example: [Delete Profiles Script v1.9](http://www.theshonkproject.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=50&Itemid=30), [script to delete user profiles and data](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1705603), [Delete Windows profiles (DeleteProfiles2K8.vbs)](http://oxacon.blogspot.ca/2011/12/delete-windows-profiles.html), etc.

Comment: @techie007 Check out Meta.  Just because you can Google it doesn't mean it's a bad question or shouldn't be answered.  Stack Exchange is to compile all those answers to show up on Google.  So answer the question and not just say Google it.

Comment: @defaultNINJA - I've been a member for almost 4 years, I've been to Meta. ;)   anyway, I didn't say "google it", nor did I suggest the question should be closed or not answered.  I pointed out that contrary to what the user suggests ("I've looked online and I cannot find a way to do this"), there's tons of info to be found on this subject with basic searching, which I provided for his own study.  I would have voted to close it if I thought it wasn't supposed to be here.  :)

Answer (score 5):

I would like to provide a little bit more up-to-date solution for others who might be looking to solve this in Windows 10

Seeing how Microsoft prefers CIM over WMI, and that Delete() method for win32_UserProfile object is hidden, one might think that method posted by @user318485 might be dropped or deprecated.

More up-to-date method of programmatically deleting user profile is with PowerShell

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_UserProfile | Where-Object {$_.LocalPath -like "*username*"} | Remove-CimInstance
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use WMIC.

```
wmic /node:localhost path win32_UserProfile where LocalPath="c:\\users\\user" Delete 2>>c:\windows\temp\wmic.err
```

Just replace localhost with the computer name and replace the "user" and the end of the local path with the domain username. It will not remove the domain profile, just the local profile data. It will attempt to remove the whole profile folder after removing the account but sometimes it will be left behind, usually empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `net` command for this.

For del user account.

```
net user YourUsername /del
```

For Add.

```
net user YourUserName YourPassword /add
```

For more info, read [`How to Use the Net User Command`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251394).

---

There is a command-line tool to do this, call [`Delprof2`](http://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/)(inofficial successor to Microsoft’s [`Delprof`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315411)).

Usage: `delprof2 [/l] [/u] [/q] [/p] [/r] [/c:[\\]<computername>] [/d:<days> [/ntuserini]] [/ed:<pattern>] [/id:<pattern>] [/i]`

```
   /l   List only, do not delete (what-if mode)
   /u   Unattended (no confirmation)
   /q   Quiet (no output and no confirmation)
   /p   Prompt for confirmation before deleting each profile
   /r   Delete local caches of roaming profiles only, not local profiles
   /c   Delete on remote computer instead of local machine
   /d   Delete only profiles not used in x days
   /ntuserini
        When determining profile age for /d, use the file NTUSER.INI
        instead of NTUSER.DAT for age calculation
   /ed  Exclude profile directories whose name matches this pattern
        Wildcard characters * and ? can be used in the pattern
        May be used more than once and can be combined with /id
   /id  Include only profile directories whose name matches this pattern
        Wildcard characters * and ? can be used in the pattern
        May be used more than once and can be combined with /ed
   /i   Ignore errors, continue deleting
```

Example of Delprof2 in action, deleting user profiles remotely.

```
delprof2.exe -c:192.168.175.129 -p
```

[image]

Comment: It works for local accounts but I'm trying to delete profile data stored on the computer from accounts that belong to a domain.

Comment: @StaticMethod This does not work? `net user YourUsername /del /domain`.

Comment: net user YourUsername /del /domain deletes the account out of the domain controller which is not what I want. I just want to delete the profile data off of the local computer. delprof2.exe is a third party utility. Company policy makes it difficult for me to use any third party utility.

Answer (score 0):

Win 7 built in 
Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> User Profile enable delete profiles after a certain time 60 days 30 days etc.