# Remove and delete certain local accounts

Tags: windows-7, command-line, user-accounts

How can I delete a user from the command line?

---

I am just starting working at a college and I'm inheriting a unintelligible mismash of local and domain accounts across a span of computers ranging from XP to Windows 8.

with upwards of two thousand computers that need to be gone through and remove anywhere between no and 5 local users accounts (so that people will start actually using their domain counterparts)

I've seen people saying [`net user username /del`](https://superuser.com/questions/643417/delete-user-profile-from-command-line-windows-7/643423#643423) which apparently misses possibly some stuff in the registry and doesn't remove the folder for `C:\users\username either`

I've seen people recommending [DelProf2](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/) which seems like it would get the job done, and has *some* filters, but has no way for me to specify which accounts to leave or delete other than direct interaction or filtering based on time (which won't work because I am changing the account they should be using)  Also, I would prefer to stay away from downloading and running a file on all of the computers and stick to regular commnands/vbscript/powershell/stuff

Most of the computers have either one or two local accounts that I would want to remove. The rest I would want to spit out to a file for my manual review (some of them have been embedded in systems and would need undoing by hand) but I can worry about that part in the script I'll be writing.

I am looking for a command line way or a set of steps to delete a given user. If doing `net user username /del` and then deleting the relevant registry keys is that, then please give some sources.

Comment: IF you would like newer/different answers to the existing version of this question, please place a bounty on the original instead of asking the same question again.

Comment: How about asking for a complete answer? I couldn't find one

Comment: It will give you a chance to comment on why you're placing the bounty.

Comment: I've seen the one you marked as duplicate and it was not completely removed. `net user username del` removed the user from being able to log in but did not remove the user folder